# Pandas transform moving two rows (of x,y) into feature columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to transform a pandas df that looks like:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

test_data = {'run': ['X', 'Y', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
             'time': [np.nan, np.nan, 10, 20, 40, 60],
             'temp': [np.nan, np.nan, 100, 120, 140, 160],
             'press': [np.nan, np.nan, 200, 220, 240, 260],
             'twist': [np.nan, np.nan, 300 ,320, 340, 360],
             'output_site_1': [0, 0, 11, 12, 13, 14],
             'output_site_2': [0, 1, 15, 16, 17, 18],
             'output_site_3': [1, 0, 19, 20, 21, 22],
             'output_site_4': [1, 1, 23, 24, 25, 26]
            }
pd.DataFrame(test_data)
```

| run | time | temp | press | twist | output_site_1 | output_site_2 | output_site_3 | output_site_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| Y | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| A | 10.0 | 100.0 | 200.0 | 300.0 | 11 | 15 | 19 | 23 |
| B | 20.0 | 120.0 | 220.0 | 320.0 | 12 | 16 | 20 | 24 |
| C | 40.0 | 140.0 | 240.0 | 340.0 | 13 | 17 | 21 | 25 |
| D | 60.0 | 160.0 | 260.0 | 360.0 | 14 | 18 | 22 | 26 |

into a df that looks like the one below:

```
transform_test_data = {'run': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D'],
                       'X': [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
                       'Y': [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                       'time': [10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 40, 40, 40, 40, 60, 60, 60, 60],
                       'temp': [100, 100, 100, 100, 120, 120, 120, 120, 140, 140, 140, 140, 160, 160, 160, 160],
                       'press': [200, 200, 200, 200, 220, 220, 220, 220, 240, 240, 240, 240, 260, 260, 260, 260],
                       'twist': [300 ,300, 300, 300, 320, 320, 320, 320, 340, 340, 340, 340, 360, 360, 360, 360],
                       'output': [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26]
                      }
pd.DataFrame(transform_test_data)
```

| run | X | Y | time | temp | press | twist | output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 0 | 10 | 100 | 200 | 300 | 11 |
| A | 0 | 1 | 10 | 100 | 200 | 300 | 12 |
| A | 1 | 0 | 10 | 100 | 200 | 300 | 13 |
| A | 1 | 1 | 10 | 100 | 200 | 300 | 14 |
| B | 0 | 0 | 20 | 120 | 220 | 320 | 15 |
| B | 0 | 1 | 20 | 120 | 220 | 320 | 16 |
| B | 1 | 0 | 20 | 120 | 220 | 320 | 17 |
| B | 1 | 1 | 20 | 120 | 220 | 320 | 18 |
| C | 0 | 0 | 40 | 140 | 240 | 340 | 19 |
| C | 0 | 1 | 40 | 140 | 240 | 340 | 20 |
| C | 1 | 0 | 40 | 140 | 240 | 340 | 21 |
| C | 1 | 1 | 40 | 140 | 240 | 340 | 22 |
| D | 0 | 0 | 60 | 160 | 260 | 360 | 23 |
| D | 0 | 1 | 60 | 160 | 260 | 360 | 24 |
| D | 1 | 0 | 60 | 160 | 260 | 360 | 25 |
| D | 1 | 1 | 60 | 160 | 260 | 360 | 26 |

I would like to take the rows 'X' and 'Y' and turn them into two seperate columns in the df and then remove them from the df. Doing so would add two new columns ('X' and 'Y') while also increasing the number for each run by run*(number-output-sites).

I need the method to be generalized such that it takes in a dataframe (like the first one) and returns a df (like the last one), can handle arbitrary number of inputs, and sites. There will always be a delineation between inputs and outputs as the first output will always be labeled 'output_site_1'.

I supplied 'test_data' and 'transformed_test_data' as dictionaries so if anyone felt kind enough to help out a stuck human (that's me!) it would be easy to create the two dataframes.

Comment: It's clear you want to know how to transform the data frame, but your logic of transformation is not clear. In other words, you should explain what you are doing to your data to have that desired output so people can help you with the coding.

Answer (score 2):

one option is to transform into long form, split into different tables, munge, then recombine. As suggested in Tim's solution, if you can do this before dumping into Pandas, that is preferable, and should be more efficient.

This solution uses [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) for the wide to long form; you can do this using `pd.wide_to_long`; [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) offers an easier abstraction and is comparably more efficient in a number of cases.

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor as jn

# reshape to long form
extract = (test_data
          .pivot_longer(index = slice('run','twist'), 
                        names_to = ('.value', 'site', 'num'), 
                        names_sep='_')
          .drop(columns='site'))

# extract X and Y rows
runs = (extract
       .loc[extract.run.isin(['X','Y'])]
       .pivot(columns='run', values='output', index='num'))

# extract non X and Y rows
others = extract.loc[~extract.run.isin(['X','Y'])]

# merge the two dataframes
(runs
.merge(others, on='num')
.drop(columns='num')
)
    X  Y run  time   temp  press  twist  output
0   0  0   A  10.0  100.0  200.0  300.0      11
1   0  0   B  20.0  120.0  220.0  320.0      12
2   0  0   C  40.0  140.0  240.0  340.0      13
3   0  0   D  60.0  160.0  260.0  360.0      14
4   0  1   A  10.0  100.0  200.0  300.0      15
5   0  1   B  20.0  120.0  220.0  320.0      16
6   0  1   C  40.0  140.0  240.0  340.0      17
7   0  1   D  60.0  160.0  260.0  360.0      18
8   1  0   A  10.0  100.0  200.0  300.0      19
9   1  0   B  20.0  120.0  220.0  320.0      20
10  1  0   C  40.0  140.0  240.0  340.0      21
11  1  0   D  60.0  160.0  260.0  360.0      22
12  1  1   A  10.0  100.0  200.0  300.0      23
13  1  1   B  20.0  120.0  220.0  320.0      24
14  1  1   C  40.0  140.0  240.0  340.0      25
15  1  1   D  60.0  160.0  260.0  360.0      26
```

If your data has just two rows for `X` and `Y`, you can avoid flipping to wide form(pivot), by doing some preprocessing; this way you get to do the flip once, and even avoid the merge (and you don't need another library :)):

```py
index = ['run', 'time', 'temp', 'press', 'twist']
temp = test_data.set_index(index)

# preprocessing begins here
cols = temp.loc[['X','Y']]
# get the output header name
output_only = cols.columns.str.split('_').str[0].tolist()
# combine and generate a MultiIndex
cols = list(cols.to_numpy()) + [output_only]
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(cols, names = ['X','Y', None])
# get rid of X and Y rows
# sorting is to avoid performance drop on MultiIndex
temp = temp.sort_index().drop(['X', 'Y'])
temp.columns = cols
# flip to long form
temp.stack(['X','Y']).reset_index()
   run  time   temp  press  twist  X  Y  output
0    A  10.0  100.0  200.0  300.0  0  0      11
1    A  10.0  100.0  200.0  300.0  0  1      15
2    A  10.0  100.0  200.0  300.0  1  0      19
3    A  10.0  100.0  200.0  300.0  1  1      23
4    B  20.0  120.0  220.0  320.0  0  0      12
5    B  20.0  120.0  220.0  320.0  0  1      16
6    B  20.0  120.0  220.0  320.0  1  0      20
7    B  20.0  120.0  220.0  320.0  1  1      24
8    C  40.0  140.0  240.0  340.0  0  0      13
9    C  40.0  140.0  240.0  340.0  0  1      17
10   C  40.0  140.0  240.0  340.0  1  0      21
11   C  40.0  140.0  240.0  340.0  1  1      25
12   D  60.0  160.0  260.0  360.0  0  0      14
13   D  60.0  160.0  260.0  360.0  0  1      18
14   D  60.0  160.0  260.0  360.0  1  0      22
15   D  60.0  160.0  260.0  360.0  1  1      26
```

Again, just wide to long form was used, so no need to flip back to wide (potentially expensive) and more importantly, merging is avoided (merging on duplicate indexes is potentially expensive as well)

Comment: I think there isn't any need to a new library... morevoer: your approach: `16.9 ms ± 4.77 ms` and mine: `8.43 ms ± 2.89 ms`

Comment: sure, I added the reason why I used the extra library. Thanks for the feedback on speed. if you do not mind, what is the speed when the data size is increased? maybe 10k rows ? 50k rows?

Comment: Yes, I found that for large datasets (10k rows), your approach is faster about 3x. but my code bottleneck is `pd.concat([df3] * (df2.size// df3.size), ignore_index=True)` that get about 90% of time. if you can tell me how I can reduce that time, I highly appreciate you, I am junior and there for learning

Comment: we are all learning :) I'd say it comes with experience, as well as going through other ppl's code

Answer (score 1):

Like many situations, this is easier handled before moving into pandas.  You really should have two different arrays there, but we can handle that in code.

```
import pandas as pd

test_data = {'run': ['X', 'Y', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
             'time': [np.nan, np.nan, 10, 20, 40, 60],
             'temp': [np.nan, np.nan, 100, 120, 140, 160],
             'press': [np.nan, np.nan, 200, 220, 240, 260],
             'twist': [np.nan, np.nan, 300 ,320, 340, 360],
             'output_site_1': [0, 0, 11, 12, 13, 14],
             'output_site_2': [0, 1, 15, 16, 17, 18],
             'output_site_3': [1, 0, 19, 20, 21, 22],
             'output_site_4': [1, 1, 23, 24, 25, 26]
            }

rows = []
store = {}
for key,row in test_data.items():
    if key == 'run':
        runs = row
    elif row[0] is np.nan:
        store[key] = { a:b for a,b in zip(runs,row) }
    else:
        row = { a:b for a,b in zip(runs, row) }
        for r in runs[2:]:
            new = [r, row['X'], row['Y']]
            new.extend( [v[r] for v in store.values()] )
            new.append( row[r] )
            rows.append( new )

columns = ['run', 'X', 'Y'] + list(store.keys()) + ['output']
df = pd.DataFrame( rows, columns=columns )
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   run  X  Y  time  temp  press  twist  output
0    A  0  0    10   100    200    300      11
1    B  0  0    20   120    220    320      12
2    C  0  0    40   140    240    340      13
3    D  0  0    60   160    260    360      14
4    A  0  1    10   100    200    300      15
5    B  0  1    20   120    220    320      16
6    C  0  1    40   140    240    340      17
7    D  0  1    60   160    260    360      18
8    A  1  0    10   100    200    300      19
9    B  1  0    20   120    220    320      20
10   C  1  0    40   140    240    340      21
11   D  1  0    60   160    260    360      22
12   A  1  1    10   100    200    300      23
13   B  1  1    20   120    220    320      24
14   C  1  1    40   140    240    340      25
15   D  1  1    60   160    260    360      26
```

If you're bothered that the order doesn't match yours, add

```
rows.sort()
```

just before making the DataFrame.

Comment: I apologize for not making my post detailed enough (please don't hate me). I appreciate your hard work and help! I need to make a general method though, that can handle arbitrary number of inputs and output_sites. This solution is hard coded and not flexible enough for what I'm looking for.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean,  This will handle any number of output sites and any number of attributes.  The only thing hard-coded is the final set of columns, and that's easy to fix from the data we have.

Answer (score 1):

```
def setter(df):
    tmp = pd.concat([df.run, df.filter(like="output_")], axis=1).set_index("run")
    df2 = tmp[2:].stack().reset_index()[["run", 0]].rename(columns={0: "output"})

    df3 = tmp[:2].T.reset_index(drop=True)

    return pd.concat([pd.concat([df3] * (df2.size// df3.size), ignore_index=True), pd.merge(df[2:][['run', 'time',  'temp', 'press',    'twist']], df2)], axis=1)
```